# Creating Ruby Array with keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok so this is simple 101 but I am obviously doing something wrong. Can you advise how I create a params array like the below.

```
params = []
params[:geo_bounding_box][:top_left_lat] = @search.ne_lat
params[:geo_bounding_box][:top_left_lon] = @search.sw_lon
params[:geo_bounding_box][:bottom_right_lat] = @search.sw_lat
params[:geo_bounding_box][:bottom_right_lon] = @search.ne_lon
```

Hope you can advise!

Comment: Arrays need integers as the argument for `[]`. So it is impossible to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html).

```
params = { 
  :geo_bounding_box => {
    :top_left_lat => @search.ne_lat,
    :top_left_lon => @search.sw_lon,
    :bottom_right_lat => @search.sw_lat,
    :bottom_right_lon => @search.me_lon
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby hashes (not arrays) are initialised with `{}` not `[]`.

```
params = {}
params[:geo_bounding_box][:top_left_lat] = @search.ne_lat
...
```

Apart from that you're on the right track!